# Find all asp:textboxes that are textmode=password and change display to none

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to find all asp:textboxes where textmode=password and change their display to none or do I need to give them all a class?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A textbox with textmode "password" will render as an `<input type="password" />`. When using JavaScript/jQuery, the only thing you need to be concerned about is the rendered output; the client will have no concept of the code that was used to render it.

To hide all, simply use:

```
$('input[type=password]').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[type="password"]').css("display", "none");
```